# regex exclude ending

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex that includes

```
1.1
2.1
```

but not `1.1.1`

I tried negative lookahead:
`\d{1}\.\d{1}^(?!\.)`

How can I exclude the strings that have a dot after the second digit?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried ?

Comment: \d{1}\.\d{1}^(?!\.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand:

`{begining of the string}{digits}{dot}{digits}{not dot}`

the regex will be:

`^\d+[.]\d+[^.]`

But if you want:

`{begining of the string}{digits}{dot}{digits}{end of String}`

you'll need:
`^\d+[.]\d+$`

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+[.]\d+$
```

As you wished, it matches `1.1, 2.1, 200.200` but not for `1.1.1`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the $? For example saying `1.1` but NOT `1.1. `, so negating the dot after the second digit?